# How to completely disable Spring Cloud Stream from trying to create topics?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have set the auto-create-topics config property to `false` for both the Kafka and Kafka Streams binders, like this:

```yaml
spring.cloud.stream:
  kafka:
    binder:
      auto-create-topics: false
    streams:
      binder:
        auto-create-topics: false
```

This stops some of the topics my app relies on from being auto-created, but others are still being created when the Spring Boot app starts up. I want to *completely* disable topic creation by the app/client.

This is not a question about disabling topic creation in the Kafka cluster itself, that is already done for "upper" environments. What I'm trying to do is provide assurance that the application itself will never try to create any topics and fail at startup if *any* topics it needs don't already exist in the cluster.

Are there other config properties I need to set?

Comment: Though it's not the config that'll solve your problem, it should help with targeting the source -`spring.kafka.listener.missing-topics-fatal=true`.
You should be good on the autoconfig that gets run with binder and binder streams, but wouldnt hurt to take a look. Theres also the spring kafka autoconfiguration  to look out for - you might be unintentionally using a producer/consumer provided by the framework

Comment: this is weird since the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html) itself indicate that setting `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics: false` will stop the app from trying to create the topic, and fails if the declared topics doesn't exists

Comment: @Nerm setting that config property did not yield any different result.

Comment: Are you creating a client without the help of the framework?

Comment: No, all our connections are made via Spring Cloud Stream configuration. I would like to post the full topology config, but I'd have to scrub it for any client-specific names first.

Comment: @E-Riz Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Ryan nope, and I moved on from that project (and quite honestly, Spring Cloud Stream - won't likely be recommending it in the future).

Answer (score 0):

This is a **read-only** Kafka broker property and you can't configure it via any client application, including Spring Boot and Spring Cloud apps. Here is what the Kafka documentation reads:

> **auto.create.topics.enable**
>
> Enable auto creation of topic on the server
> Type: boolean
> Default:  true
> Valid Values:
> Importance:   high
> Update Mode:  **read-only**

Reference: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_auto.create.topics.enable